# Django RSS Feed Problems

Tags: python, django, django-rss

I'm working on a blogging application, and trying to made just a simple RSS feed system function. However, I'm running into an odd bug that doesn't make a lot of sense to me. I understand what's likely going on, but I don't understand why. My RSS Feed class is below:

```
class RSSFeed(Feed):
    title = settings.BLOG_NAME
    description = "Recent Posts"
    def items(self):
        return Story.objects.all().order_by('-created')[:10]

    def link(self, obj):
        return obj.get_absolute_url()
```

However I received the following error (full stack trace at http://dpaste.com/82510/):

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

That leads me to believe that it's not receiving any objects whatsoever. However, I can drop to a shell and grab those Story objects, and I can iterate through them returning the absolute url without any problems. So it would seem both portions of the Feed work, just not when it's in feed form. Furthermore, I added some logging, and can confirm that the items function is *never* entered when visiting the feeds link. I'm hoping I'm just overlooking something simple. Thanks in advance for any/all help.

Answer (score 4):

Changing to:

```
class RSSFeed(Feed):
    title = settings.BLOG_NAME
    link = "/blog/"
    description = "Recent Posts"

    def items(self):
        return Story.objects.all().order_by('-created')[:10]
```

Fixed it. Not sure I totally understand it.. but whatev. :)

Comment: Perhaps it expected link to take no arguments other than self, but you provided obj too

Comment: Thanks for this. Annoying that if you don't provide the link property it craps itself. If it's required, let me know that.

Answer (score 1):

have you defined

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
```

in the model?

also, it's nice to

```
if not obj:
    raise FeedDoesNotExist
```

to avoid errors when feed result is not present